# Squid: The request or reply is too large

Tags: squid

I have done a reverse proxy with an Apache in the background (on the same server). All works great but I can't open one page.

I get the error "The request or reply is too large."

In my cache.log contains:

```
2010/12/09 15:28:29| WARNING: http.c:971: HTTP header too large
2010/12/09 15:29:03| ctx: enter level  0: 'http://server/admin/cms/nav'
2010/12/09 15:29:03| httpProcessReplyHeader: Too large reply header
2010/12/09 15:29:03| ctx: exit level  0
```

In my squid.conf i disabled the limitations of the request and reply header, without success:

```
reply_body_max_size 0 allow all
request_body_max_size 0
```

Does someone know why that don't work?

Thank you very much.

Squid Version:

```
Squid Cache: Version 2.7.STABLE3
configure options:  '--prefix=/usr' '--exec_prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/sbin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--libexecdir=/usr/lib/squid' '--sysconfdir=/etc/squid' '--localstatedir=/var/spool/squid' '--datadir=/usr/share/squid' '--enable-async-io' '--with-pthreads' '--enable-storeio=ufs,aufs,coss,diskd,null' '--enable-linux-netfilter' '--enable-arp-acl' '--enable-epoll' '--enable-removal-policies=lru,heap' '--enable-snmp' '--enable-delay-pools' '--enable-htcp' '--enable-cache-digests' '--enable-underscores' '--enable-referer-log' '--enable-useragent-log' '--enable-auth=basic,digest,ntlm,negotiate' '--enable-negotiate-auth-helpers=squid_kerb_auth' '--enable-carp' '--enable-follow-x-forwarded-for' '--with-large-files' '--with-maxfd=65536' 'amd64-debian-linux' 'build_alias=amd64-debian-linux' 'host_alias=amd64-debian-linux' 'target_alias=amd64-debian-linux' 'CFLAGS=-Wall -g -O2' 'LDFLAGS=' 'CPPFLAGS='
```

Comment: I updated to Version 3.1 (Debian Backports), now it's working.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is large reply header, so you can increase it.
Default value is 20KB so you can increase it. For example by this command

```
reply_header_max_size 200 KB
```